# Intercept a socket call made by an app and map it to a custom socket

Tags: java, android, c++, c, sockets

I am developing an android app which connects to internet. I will be using androids default httpconnection classes to access the web. What i want to do is to intercept the socket calls made by http connections and map it to a custom socket call.

The custom socket call is written in JNI using C . Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you will need rooted device to achieve this.

The easiest way you can do it is probably using JNI + iptables + [Netfilter Library](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/).

Comment: I only need to map the socket calls made by my application. Not the entire socket calls in device. Is it possible with this . Also is there any way to achieve this in an unrooted device ?